# Getting a list of the rendered items

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have my own custom component. This component extends from a basic container. I want to be able to access the itemRenderer instances that are being visualized. I know that the component mx:list  has an internal getter that provides an array of Arrays containing the itemRenderer instances that render each data provider item. I want the same thing. Any idea how of how to do that?

To be more specific: I am setting the selected property of my dataProvider items to true or false. From the updateDisplayList funcion of my ItemRenderer I check for changes of the property and correct the border color of the selected ones. Unfortunately I have to force the updateDisplayList function. I already did this once on a ItemRenderer from a list. Only with the list it was practical because by making my own list I was able to get the list of items being rendered and therefore visualized (cannot be many). It was no overhead to go trough the rendered Items and updateDisplayList. But in this case I can have 100 items. Imagine checking and changing styles on so many items. Thanks

Comment: In Flex 3 the container classes like `Container`, `VBox`, `HBox`, and `Canvas` do not use item renderers. Only the list based controls do (`List`, `HorizontalList`, `DataGrid`, etc).  The container classes merely render the child objects that are added to them. In Flex 4 there is a `DataGroup` container class that uses item renderers, but no such container in Flex 3.

Comment: The question here is why would you want to access the renderers? You need to let the renderers do what they do best and that's render. There is nothing you can't calculate from a combination of the control and dataprovider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flex architects intentionally made this difficult to do, because they are properly encapsulating the component. In short, to even try to do this is a violation of good OOP principles.

That said, about 90% of the things you are probably trying to do can be done by manipulating the data item, and the remaining 10% can be done by using a ClassFactory for your itemRenderer that sets a custom property on your itemRenderer to a callback where you can look at the data available to the containing context and provide back a value based on that.

If you elaborate a bit more on your end goal, I can give you more specifics.

---

Edit in light of clarification:

You need to make your data object class dispatch an event when it changes (one way is to make it bindable, or just make the selected property bindable). Then, in your renderer, listen for the change event and take the appropriate action.

A second way to handle this would just be to refresh() the collection, storing the selectedItem first (if you care about that) and resetting it once the refresh has finished.

Comment: _I elaborated a bit more my question you can read it above. Right now I am going through the full list of itemRenderers and invalidating the display list. But I would like to do that only on the visualized ones. By making my own list based on Adobe mx:List I was able to access the listItems which is an internal var that holds exactly that: A list of the actual rendered Item. On a practical sense the number of items being visualized can never be that many.But with a component based on a container I don't know how.Thanks_

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access the itemRenderer instances through getChildAt method.  Flex 3's container overrides "getChildAt", "numChildren", given that some children are logical children, while some are decorative children such as background, border and scrollbars.

Keep in mind that itemRenderer may not right away become available upon dataProvider assignment, as they may be created during the next component lifecycle.  Check with the underlying container's documentation and find out which event to be listened when the renderers are surely created, so you can reliably access them.